# How to install vtk with gl2ps enabled using conda

Tags: python, compilation, vtk, anaconda, conda

I am using anaconda, and I've built vtk with conda using

```
conda install vtk
```

The default build of vtk is without [gl2ps](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkGL2PSExporter.html), and I want to know how can I build (or rather rebuild) vtk with gl2ps enabled using conda.

I am actually tring to execture this example code:

```
 from mayavi import mlab
 mlab.test_plot3d()
 mlab.savefig(temp.eps)
```

but get the error

```
Saving as a vector PS/EPS/PDF/TeX file using GL2PS is either not supported by your version of VTK or you have not configured VTK to work with GL2PS -- read the documentation for the vtkGL2PSExporter class.
```

Thank You

**EDIT**

I downloaded the coda-recipes

```
git clone https://github.com/conda/conda-recipes.git
```

and even if I do not edit the files to include gl2ps

```
BUILD START: vtk-5.10.1-py27_1
Fetching package metadata: ......
Solving package specifications: .
The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    setuptools-13.0.2          |           py27_0         435 KB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    cmake:      3.0.1-0      
    openssl:    1.0.1k-0     
    pip:        6.0.8-py27_0 
    python:     2.7.9-1      
    readline:   6.2-2        
    setuptools: 13.0.2-py27_0
    sqlite:     3.8.4.1-0    
    system:     5.8-1        
    tk:         8.5.15-0     
    zlib:       1.2.8-0      

Fetching packages ...
setuptools-13. 100% |######################################################################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00 463.16 kB/s
Extracting packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ] |########################################################################################################################################################################################################| 100%
Linking packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ] |########################################################################################################################################################################################################| 100%
Source cache directory is: /home/users/user/anaconda/conda-bld/src_cache
Downloading source to cache: vtk-5.10.1.tar.gz
An unexpected error has occurred, please consider sending the
following traceback to the conda GitHub issue tracker at:

    https://github.com/conda/conda-build/issues

Include the output of the command 'conda info' in your report.


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/users/user/anaconda/bin/conda-build", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda_build/main_build.py", line 110, in main
    args_func(args, p)
  File "/home/users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda_build/main_build.py", line 308, in args_func
    args.func(args, p)
  File "/home/users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda_build/main_build.py", line 268, in execute
    build.build(m, verbose=not args.quiet, post=post)
  File "/home/users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda_build/build.py", line 304, in build
    source.provide(m.path, m.get_section('source'))
  File "/home/users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda_build/source.py", line 221, in provide
    unpack(meta)
  File "/home/users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda_build/source.py", line 60, in unpack
    src_path = download_to_cache(meta)
  File "/home/users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda_build/source.py", line 48, in download_to_cache
    download(meta['url'], path)
KeyError: 'url'
```

Comment: Did you manage to build in the end?
I'm having troubles finding out how to edit the build.sh from @asmeurer's answer to incorporate gl2ps in the build.

Comment: @Løiten I managed to compile it with the recipe, but did not try to incorporate gl2ps yet..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recipe used to build vtk is [here](https://github.com/conda/conda-recipes/tree/master/vtk). You should modify it to include that package and build with with `conda build vtk/`.

Comment: I fixed the recipe. Do a `git pull` and try again.